# Javascript App - What about my code?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I obfuscate JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript)

I built a web app for a client running in javascript. What is the best way to "protect" my code? All of the code for the app can be seen in FireBug etc ?

Is there any way?

Comment: The best way to protect your code is to keep it visible only to yourself (jk). No, you can't do any total protection. However, you can minify and pack it, to make it harder for the newbies to come and steal from you.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to make it hard to anyone to understand the code by using an [obfuscator](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20obfuscator).